# Meaning of "\advance\leftskip \@tempdima \null\nobreak\hskip -\leftskip"

Tags: macros

I am a novice of LaTeX, and I encounter the following code which I can't understand fully.

```
\def\@dottedtocline#1#2#3#4#5{%
  \ifnum #1>\c@tocdepth tt\else
    \vskip \z@ \@plus.2\p@
    {\leftskip #2 \relax \rightskip \@tocrmarg \parfillskip -\rightskip
     \parindent #2 \relax\@afterindenttrue
     \interlinepenalty\@M
     \leavevmode
     \@tempdima #3 \relax
     \advance\leftskip \@tempdima \null\nobreak\hskip -\leftskip
     {#4}\nobreak
     \leaders\hbox{$\m@th\mkern 1.5mu\cdot\mkern 1.5mu$}\hfill
     \nobreak
     \hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hfil\normalfont \normalcolor #5}%
     \par}%
  \fi}
```

The first is

```
\leftskip #2 \relax \rightskip \@tocrmarg \parfillskip -\rightskip
     \parindent #2 \relax\@afterindenttrue
```

Could somebody explain it to me in detail?

The second

```
\advance\leftskip \@tempdima \null\nobreak\hskip -\leftskip
```

What's the meaning of it, why using `\hskip -\leftskip` and what is the meaning of `\advance\leftskip \@tempdima`?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your question is likely to get more attention if you tell us _why_ it's important to you. Can you provide a complete small document showing where you hope to use it to do some particular thing?

Comment: Explaining arbitrary low-level TeX isn't really that helpful in most cases: as @EthanBolker suggests, a more profitable route is likely to be to give some indication of what you are after. If you really just want to learn what is going on here that is fine but it might be useful then to give some idea of how much (La)TeX you know.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The code presumably isn't intended to be read by a novice LaTeX user but...

```
\def\@dottedtocline#1#2#3#4#5{%
```

a macro with 5 arguments

```
  \ifnum #1>\c@tocdepth tt\else
```

If `#1`  is deeper than the limit for the table of contents depth typeset `tt` (a typo??)
Otherwise

```
    \vskip \z@ \@plus.2\p@
```

add a small vertical space between 0 and .2pt

```
    {\leftskip #2 \relax
```

set `\leftskip` (space before left edge of paragraph) to `#2`

```
            \rightskip \@tocrmarg
```

set `\rightskip` to `\@tocrmarg`

```
           \parfillskip -\rightskip
```

set `\parfillskip` (extra space at end of paragraph) to `-\rightskip` so it cancels out the `\rightskip`, ensuring the paragraph ends flush with the right margin.

```
     \parindent #2 \relax
```

set paragraph indent to `#2`

```
     \@afterindenttrue
```

set this boolean flag to true, to control indentation of first paragraph after the heading.

```
     \interlinepenalty\@M
```

prevent page breaks between lines

```
     \leavevmode
```

start a paragraph

```
     \@tempdima #3 \relax
```

set this temporary register to `#3`

```
     \advance\leftskip \@tempdima
```

Increase the left skip by the value just stored

```
      \null
```

add an empty box to the paragraph just started

```
       \nobreak\hskip -\leftskip
```

back up by the left skip so as to make the first line *not* be indented by `\leftskip`

```
     {#4}
```

typeset or otherwise do whatever is in `#4`

```
     \nobreak
```

prevent a break at this point

```
     \leaders\hbox{$\m@th\mkern 1.5mu\cdot\mkern 1.5mu$}\hfill
```

make a row of dots

```
     \nobreak
```

prevent a break

```
     \hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hfil\normalfont \normalcolor #5}%
```

set `#5` in a box of fixed width `\@pnumwidth`

```
     \par}%
```

end the paragraph and the group

```
  \fi}
```

end the if test

Comment: you might mention which documentation (pdf output from dtx file) can be found.  i haven't looked, but suspect the documentation there, while essentially what you've said, might have other useful information, especially if this person wants to go exploring further.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I have no idea where the code in the question came from (is not the definition of `\@dottedtocline` in the latex format) the standard definition is documented in source2e.pdf but not with line by line comments.

Comment: Thank you so much Carlisle, you are always so helpful. This class file is a Thesis and the code I posted is the toc code. I am however, still have some confusion"\advance\leftskip \@tempdima \null\nobreak\hskip -\leftskip" why advance before then minus it again? and How could I Post the whole file, thank you again! :)

Comment: The whole file could be download here
http://www.ctex.org/PackagePostDocRep/files.xml?action=download&file=PostDocRep-v0.1e.zip In fact, I still puzzled by the command `\@afterindenttrue` how does it work in this thesis.
the second is `\advance\leftskip \@tempdima \null\nobreak\hskip -\leftskip` why you first `\advance \leftskip \@tempdima` then you back up it by `\leftskip`, I couldn't find its effect after I compiling it. Could you demo it by using an obvious example. Thank you.

Comment: @popular You can not learn a language (any language) by jumping in to the middle of a large existing document and asking what fragments mean, you need to back up and start with easy tutorials. the `\advance` changes the leftskip register which changes the left margin for _all_ following text until the end of the group, the `\hskip-\leftskip`  is adding _one_ negative space of that amount at one place and not changing any registers. So the two bits of code are not really comparable.

Comment: Thank you Prof. Carlisle, I have got it completely with you great help. Could you give me some suggestions of materials which cover the explanations of command such as \hskip, \@afterindenttrue, etc. They are hard to find at times.

Comment: @popular Please note that the way the site works, the space for  answers is not really supposed to be used for comments: I've converted your ones. As I'm sure David will tell also you, `\hskip` is a a very different thing from the `\@afterindent` switch. The former is a TeX primitive, so documented in for example _The TeXbook_, the latter is a LaTeX kernel command for controlling sections. As David has said, trying to learn (La)TeX programming by diving into a rather complicated code block is not really a great plan: focus on one thing at a time.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable suggestions. I have learned a lot with Prof. Carlisle, you and other anonymous' kind help.