# Table of Content, indentation within long title

Tags: table-of-contents, indentation

My question is similar to following one:
[Table of Contents: Nice Titles for Parts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31458/table-of-contents-nice-titles-for-parts)

However, the solution didn't help me enough to resolve my problem.

My question is:
In the Table Of Content, I have a title holding on two line, and I need to have the second line of my title indented of .25inch from the first line.

The definition of `\l@part` in the TOC definition of the package I use is the following:

```
\newcommand\l@part[2]{%
\ifnum \c@tocdepth >-2\relax
\addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
\addvspace{2.25em \@plus\p@}%
\begingroup
  \setlength\@tempdima{3em}%
  \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
  \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
  {\leavevmode
   \bfseries #1\hfil \hbox to\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}}\par
   \nobreak
     \global\@nobreaktrue
     \everypar{\global\@nobreakfalse\everypar{}}
\endgroup
\fi}
```

I tried to add the following before `\nobreak`:

```
\advance\leftskip\@tempdima% NEW: comment out if no indentation required for lines 2,3,...
```

I'm sure that I'm missing a small thing to make everything work, but I can't figure it out. Also, I don't think this solution would work since I need to specify the space of `.25''`.

The solution given seems to only indent the second line as much as the first line. So I added `\hspace{.25in}` after `\leftskip` but it didn't work neither.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Gonzalo's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31458/11232) modified.

```
\documentclass{book}

\makeatletter
\def\@part[#1]#2{%
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax
      \refstepcounter{part}%
      \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\protect\numberline{\thepart}#1}%NEW
    \else
      \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}%
    \fi
    \markboth{}{}%
    {\centering
     \interlinepenalty \@M
     \normalfont
     \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax
       \huge\bfseries \partname\nobreakspace\thepart
       \par
       \vskip 20\p@
     \fi
     \Huge \bfseries #2\par}%
    \@endpart}
\renewcommand*\l@part[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
    \vskip 1.0em \@plus\p@
    \setlength\@tempdima{3.3em}%NEW: indentation for lines 2,3,... change according to your needs
    \begingroup
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      \leavevmode\large\bfseries\hangindent0.25in\hangafter1    %% here changed
      \advance\leftskip\@tempdima% NEW: comment out if no indentation required for lines 2,3,...
      \hskip -\leftskip
      #1\nobreak\hfil \nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}\par
      \penalty\@highpenalty
    \endgroup
  \fi}\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{Test part one with a really really long title spanning two lines}
\part{Test part two with a really really long title spanning two lines}
\part{Test part three with a really really long title spanning two lines}
\part{Test part four with a really really long title spanning two lines}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I have added `\hangindent0.25in\hangafter1` at the appropriate place.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I tried to add this command at different places with 5in but it doesn't make any difference. My definition is a bit different than the one from Gonzalo, so could it be overwrite by something else?

Comment: @user1527152 Replace your definition of `\l@part` with the one in the answer.

Comment: Already tried it break everything.

Comment: I just replace the part after \leavemode and made some modification and now it work

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. What I did is

```
\newcommand\l@part[2]{%
\ifnum \c@tocdepth >-2\relax
\addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
\addvspace{2.25em \@plus\p@}%
\begingroup
  \setlength\@tempdima{3em}%
  \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
  \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
  
  % i started changing from here

  \leavevmode                  % removed the opening brace
  \bfseries
  \advance\leftskip\@tempdima  % added this line
  \hskip -\leftskip            % added this line too
  #1\hfil \hbox to\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}\par % removed the closing brace
  \nobreak
  \global\@nobreaktrue
  \everypar{\global\@nobreakfalse\everypar{}}
\endgroup
\fi}
```

try this. I don't know what was the problem. I got some ideas from here: [Meaning of "\advance\leftskip \@tempdima \null\nobreak\hskip -\leftskip"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/197360/meaning-of-advance-leftskip-tempdima-null-nobreak-hskip-leftskip?rq=1)