# Long chapter titles not aligning correctly in ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, indentation, titletoc

I am having trouble formatting the ToC for a book. I have long chapter titles which wrap onto two lines of ToC text. The problem is that the second line of a single chapter title is aligned with the chapter number, but I need it to align with the beginning of the title text on the first line:

[image]

I am using the `titletoc` package.

```
\documentclass[twoside,openany,10pt]{book}  
\usepackage[paperwidth=5in, paperheight=8in, bindingoffset=0.375in, top=0.7in, bottom=0.7in, left=0.5in, right=0.5in]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.3}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage {setspace}
\usepackage{librebaskerville}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{letterspace}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titletoc}%
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[overload]{textcase}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[symbol]{footmisc}
\usepackage{enumerate}


\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}

\titlecontents{chapter}% <section-type>
  [0pt]% <left>
  {\small}% <above-code>
  {\thecontentslabel . \quad}% <numbered-entry-format>
  {}% <numberless-entry-format>
  {\hfill\contentspage}% <filler-page-format>

%Begin Document
\begin{document} 

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Order Of Visualization}

\chapter{How To Attract To Yourself The Things You Desire}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the argument for the `<left>` margin in `\titleformat`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}  

\usepackage{titletoc,xpatch}%

\titlecontents{chapter}% <section-type>
  [1.5em]% [0pt]% <left>
  {\small}% <above-code>
  {\hspace*{-1.5em}\makebox[1.5em][l]{\thecontentslabel.}}% <numbered-entry-format>
  {}% <numberless-entry-format>
  {\hfill\contentspage}% <filler-page-format>

\begin{document} 

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.}

\chapter{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut mattis sapien id purus tincidunt imperdiet.}

\end{document}
```

You can adjust `1.5em` to suit your needs. It's the default used by the `book` document class.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It worked well. However, I just saw that some page numbers are not aligned right. Do you know how I could force them to be on the right?

Comment: @Lisa: You need to be more specific. All the page numbers in a minimal example ToC are right aligned.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/244952/table-of-content-indentation-within-long-title) there is a solution to this problem. I tried it on your MWE and it looks like it's working. I hope it solves your problem too.